# PHP If statement with Special charactes

Tags: php, file-io

How can i create an If Statement or Function that if finds the special character '}' then in the next character will put a `<br>`?

```
$myfile = fopen("result.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($myfile)) {
    echo fgetc($myfile);
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Replace `}` with `<br>`?

Comment: No, after the character } will put a <br>

Comment: Replace `}` with `}<br />` then?

Comment: If finds the special character } then it will change line like '\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just read the contents of the file and then do a replacement.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$contents = str_replace('}', '}<br>', $contents);
echo $contents;
```

If you just want a newline after the closing curly brace then just change the line to:

```
$contents = str_replace('}', "}\n", $contents);
```

If you want to save it again then you can do it like this:

```
if ( ! file_put_contents('file.txt', $contents)) {
    echo 'Error. File could not be saved!';
}
```